# Attr not working

Tags: html, css, attr

I am trying to specify a background image using an attribute from my element; like so:

```
.gallery-tile {
    background-image: attr(data-thumbnail url, '');
}
```

Though no images are loading, is someone able to explain why this does not working? I followed the specification's as laid out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but
>   support for properties other than content is experimental.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

It's an experimental feature and the only supported attribute is `content`.